# Tool/script to search my saved commands (not bash history) from linux command line

Tags: linux, bash

In linux/bash, reverse-i-search (Ctrl+R ) searches only the history

Is there a package so I could (like reverse-i-search) :

```
a ) save a command that I like
b ) search the saved list of commands - much like reverse-i-search ?
```

The problem with alias and adding it to .bash_profile is that they are not modifiable. 
e.g., I frequently use 'git rebase -i HEAD~NUM' I could only alias certain NUM where as using reverse-i-search I could retrieve the command, edit it and execute it .

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a tool? Can't you just maintain a text file?

Comment: its not convenient especially if you are a developer

Comment: Really? You are overgeneralizing. Developers work in all kinds of ways. Text is the universal interface, and I can do everything with it and write all kinds of tools (and I do).

Comment: Anyway, you might be interested in the tons of tools that let you expand snippets. On OS X typically recommended are TextExpander, Dash, etc. In Emacs usually recommended is yasnippet. I'm not too familiar with other environments (I do Linux development from OS X anyway), so I can't say what's the best.

Comment: By the way, this looks like a shopping list question so it will probably be voted close.

Comment: may be i should have said developer working in linux ? tools help work efficiently much like the reason why reverse-i-search exist. You could always search .bash_history and modify it and execute it but Ctrl+R saves time.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say you should maintain a text file just to open it in a text editor and search in it. You can always bind Ctrl+R to searching your custom database if you know how to do that. Or you can do all kinds of magic. I just mean people work differently, so you should probably roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- Just add them to your history and search them up with Ctrl+R.

  If you've been avoiding that because you find lines disappearing from history, that's [configurable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/088).
- Add them as aliases and use `bind '"\C-k": alias-expand-line'`. This will let you type e.g. `myalias`, hit Ctrl+K, and it will expand into the full command which you can then modify.
- Write functions that accept parameters, like `rebase() { git rebase -i HEAD~$1; }` so you don't need to modify it. You can just run `rebase 4`.

Comment: Add it to search history? Like append to bash history? Also there is this problem of max history in a month that command will disappear

Comment: @purpletech Yes. And if you keep reading, you'll find that concern addressed with a link saying how to avoid losing any history lines ever. Also note that these are three separate suggestions, only the first of which relies on history at all.

Comment: Ideally i would like to have a second file/database for my saved commands and leave the bash history alone.

Comment: @purpletech Ok. Are the two suggestions that leave your bash history alone suitable instead?

Answer (score 1):

### Save your command

Here's my work around `save.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
if [ -z $1 ] && [ -z $2 ] ; then
echo 'not enough param'
else
echo 'alias' $2'="'$1'"' >> ~/.bash_aliases;
echo 'done';
fi
```

This will store a new alias in your `bash_aliases` file so you can call it later.
Just place it wherever you want, remember to chmod it as executable.

Usage:

```
$ ./save.sh 'echo nice' ncm
# this will refresh your bash alias so you dont have 
$ source ~/.bashrc to restart terminal or open new one.
$ ncm
nice
```

### History Expansion

Moreover, you can search your history for last command, and execute it:

```
 !! #to run last command again
 !!:p #to print last command
```

Or `!prefix` to run last command that match prefix E.g:

```
 ~$ !echo
 echo nice #my last echo command
```

For more document: [History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple scheme that allows searching through history from the shell prompt that returns `grep` like results for any term in history I am interested in at the moment. There isn't any magic, just set up the number of entries you want to maintain in your history, and the way you want history to behave (e.g. `ignoreboth:erasedups` to not add commands to your history list that begin with *whitespace* and to ignore duplicate entries. `erasedups` is included to weed out any duplicates caused by use of, or moving portions of other history files into use that may contain duplicates)

You can simply `export` the history control values from your `.bashrc` (or similar startup file in whatever shell you use), e.g. to keep a tidy list of 20K commands in history you could do:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=20000
export HISTSIZE=20000
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

(you also have the `HISTIGNORE` environment variable that allows you more fine grained control of what does, or doesn't, get added to your history file.)

With a tidy history file, you can make convenient use of all value contained in your history file with a short function in your `.bashrc` (or appropriate startup file) followed by a convenient `alias` to call the function. For example:

```
showhist() {
    [ -z "$1" ] && { printf "usage:  hist <search term>\n"; return 1; }
    history | grep "$1"
    return 0
}

alias hist='showhist'
```

The `showhist` function expects a *single_search* term to search through you history entries. I don't like to type so I further `alias` the function to simply `hist`. If you fail to provide any input, a short *usage:* reminder of what is expected is printed.

So when I want to recall a command I haven't run in a while along with any arguments it took, (say for installing `grub2` on Arch), I simply issue the command:

```
# hist grub
   99  pacman -S grub
  100  grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
  101  grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
  211  vi /boot/grub/grub.cfg
 <snip>
```

A simple highlight of the needed command and a middle-mouse paste in the command line and I've retrieved the infrequently used command simply by typing `hist grub` at the prompt ... done.

If you are looking for something similar, give this approach a try. Depending on how heavily you use the command line, it will take a while to build your full set of commands, but regardless, this setup is immediately useful if you have a current history file.